# Do implementations of interface javax.transaction.Transaction need to be thread safe?

Tags: java, transactions, infinispan-10

Do conforming implementations of `javax.transaction.Transaction` need to be thread safe?

Are implementations of this expected to handle concurrent requests from different threads?

As an example:

```
// Thread A
transaction.commit();

// Thread B, while that commit is still running
transaction.setRollbackOnly();
```

I am asking this question because I can see Infinispan interacting with the transaction manager in this way which results in a deadlock.  I want to understand if this is a bug in Infinispan or the transaction manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JTA](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jta-1_2-mrel2-eval-spec/JTA1.2Specification.pdf) says, that:

§3.3 - Transaction Interface

> The `Transaction.commit` and `Transaction.rollback` methods allow the target object to be comitted or rolled back. The calling thread **is not required to have the same transaction associated with the thread**. If the calling thread is not allowed to commit the transaction, the transaction manager throws an exception.

Specification does not say anything more about this point; therefore, it is not required, *pre se*, that the vendor must provide a *thread-safe* implementation of `javax.transaction.Transaction`.